# ReactJs: Redirect automatically when hitting a specific url is hit

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I am new at `react.js` and I am trying to redirect the to `/movies` if the url is `/`.

I found some ways but they were either beyond my current understanding or not `react-ish`.

App.tsx

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Layout from "./components/layouts/Backend";
import Movies from "./pages/movies/Index";

...

export default () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                <Route path="movies" element={<Movies />} />

                ...
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Currently, an empty layout is loaded whenever I enter `http://localhost:5173`. Therefore, I have to manually click the `Movies` link to redirect.

I want this to redirect to `http://localhost:5173/movies` automatically.

Comment: Since you're using React Router, check its documentation for [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect). However, if `movies` is your main component, you'd just make it available at the root url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an index route with Navigate component should do the trick

```
<Route
  index
  element={ <Navigate to="/movies" /> } 
/>
```